# how to stream terminal on webpage w/ python

Tags: python, streaming, vps

How would I go about streaming a terminal from my VPS onto a webpage with python? I would want it to look something like this:
[webpage w/ terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f69Us.jpg)

I appreciate any advice thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/) ?

> Gate One is an HTML5 web-based terminal emulator and SSH client.

It's written in python and doesn't require browser plugins.